# MySQL: Queries get slower after adding and removing a column

Tags: mysql

I've been searching everywhere and i cannot find an answer to my issue
i realized that if i add (many) columns to a table and then remove them, queries get slower permanently, i did this to test:

table: has 10 columns

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE examplecolumnnotindex = 1000;
Empty set (average: 0.26 sec) //the table has a lot of rows
```

then, i added 20 columns

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE examplecolumnnotindex = 1000;
Empty set (average: 1.28 sec)
```

then, i removed those 20 columns

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE examplecolumnnotindex = 1000;
Empty set (average: 1.02 sec)
```

and finally, i tried duplicating the table

```
CREATE TABLE  testtable LIKE table; 
INSERT INTO testtable SELECT * FROM table;

SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE examplecolumnnotindex = 1000;
Empty set (average: 0.56 sec)
```

duplicating the second table results on the same average (0.56 sec)

the averages were calculated with 10,000 queries

so, my question is why does this happen? is there something left of those columns after i drop them? this is my best guess since duplicating the table reduces the time, even though it's not the same as in the beginning

thanks in advance, and im sorry if it's something obvious or anything, im very new to mysql!

Comment: I'm confuzed why duplication is failing to speed it up. Rather than Create Table use OPTIMIZE TABLE `table`; . Can you provide all the SQL please for easier replication of issue? Is this MYISAM or Inodb storage?

Comment: yes, i've tried to use optimize table before, but the queries took even longer time (from 1.28 to 1.43 avg), i've been reading the docs about optimize table and i don't think it's related to my issue